# Url rewriting in apache2 not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite url for my php application but its not working.

My directory structure

```
/var/www/html/test|
                  |---.htaccess
                  |---index.php
```

My .htaccess file content

```
# Activates URL rewriting (like myproject.com/controller/action/1/2/3)
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`apache2ctl -M`  result:

```
rewrite_module (shared)
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

what i did wrong in the process? please help

Comment: Whenever I try `localhost/test/something/something_more` it gives not found error. shouldn't it redirect to index.php?

Comment: no errors . but  in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`  `AccessFileName .htaccess` is uncommented

Answer (score 2):

Its Working fine now.

I just change my   `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride ALL
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: So, `.htaccess` files were previously disabled then.